# D855 CM13 Nightly to Lineage 14.1 Nightly Upgrade

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg-g3, lineageos

I have the latest nightly build of CM13(cm-13.0-20161108-NIGHTLY-d855.zip) installed on my LG G3(d855). And I want to upgrade it to Lineage OS 14.1 nightly builds(for example latest right now: lineage-14.1-20170529-nightly-d855-signed.zip).

Is it possible to upgrade without wiping the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer:

If you already have CM or an unofficial AOSP based ROM, you don't have to wipe your device - in the download section there's an "experimental" build that you can install over your existing AOSP based ROM and it will migrate you to LOS without needing to wipe (potentially - it may not work and boot loop, in which case you'd need to wipe anyway).

To install:

1. Download both the nightly/weekly/stable version of LOS 14.1 and the "experimental" image.
2. Boot to TWRP
3. Install the "experimental" build
4. Reboot

   - After a reboot, the system should load and a watermark saying "cm to lineage migration build" should be all over the screen. If this is the case - everything worked fine! Continue to the next step. If it didn't boot, just reboot to TWRP and wipe the device as per the instructions above and continue with the instructions in the article.
   - If everything went fine, reboot, go back to TWRP, install the regular image and reboot back to a fully working Lineage OS.

Reference:

- In the following [web page](https://www.hacksandgeeks.com/single-post/2017/01/24/Official-Lineage-OS-141-for-LG-G3-d855) in the comment section by someone called: [Oded Arbel · Software Architect at Greenfield Technologies Ltd](https://www.facebook.com/guss77)

However, now I need to find experimental build which was removed from LineageOS download section couple of months ago.

Thanks anyways